# inserting non printable character in DB2

Tags: db2

How can I insert non printable characters in  one of the columns of DB2 table.

For example, I need to insert new line character and carriage return in one of the columns for testing purpose.

I am using DB2V9.

Please advice.

Comment: On what platform?  And how are you performing the inserts?  You're going to have to show some code here.

Comment: I got it, for carriage return, we could use the below code <code>update emp set empname='RECEIVING'||chr(10)||'COMP 01' where empno=123</code> . For new line character, we could use chr(13)

Answer (score 1):

To specify characters in a single-byte character set [SBCS] that are not mapped to your keyboard you can use hexadecimal literal.  For example, you mention chr(10), which would be written as X'0A' or x'0a', and chr(13) would be x'0d'.  Both characters together would be x'0a0d'.

See [Constants in the SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000731.htm) in the [DB2-LUW v9 Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp)

Answer (score -1):

Try This 
for printing 
"Hi 
I am good"

```
try <pre tag both open and close>
```

insert statement `"Hi<pre></pre> I am good"`